# How to change the styles of the following links?

Tags: html, css

Here i have some code from my website I'm making. I'm having trouble styling the links within css. I'm not sure why they won't change. Also the reason I've used class is because i have this code repeated 4 times (don't worry about why :P) Btw I've also tried putting the 'a' infront of .profileLinks that didnt work either :(

Here is the external CSS style sheet

```css
#trends .profileLinks a:link{
    color:#0000FF;
    text-decoration:none;
    background: transparent;
}

#trends .profileLinks a:visited {
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #0000FF; 
    background: transparent;
}
```

And here is the Html Code

```html
<div id="trends">
    <h1> Trends... </h1>
    <a href="#" title="Profile Image"><img src="logo.png" alt="Profile Image" height="59" width="68"> </a>
    <a class="profileLinks" href="#" title="User's Profile Name"> Mark Fonacier </a>
    <a class= "commentLinks" onClick ="javascript:ShowHide('HiddenDiv')" href="javascript:;" ><i>Comment</i></a>
    <br/>
    <p>
        PostPostPostPostPostPostPostPostPostPostPostPostPostPostPostPostPostPostPostPostPostPostPostPostPostPost
    </p>
    <a onClick ="javascript:ShowHide('HiddenDiv')" href="javascript:;" ><i>Comment</i></a>
    <div class="mid" id="HiddenDiv" style="DISPLAY: none" >
        <form method="post" action="">
            <textarea name="comments" cols="60" rows="2" placeholder="Enter your comments here..." maxlength="1000"> 
                </textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <br/>
```

Comment: There might be overridden to your style, try adding `!important` see if works or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This selector,

```
#trends .profileLinks a:link
```

will only work for child `<a>` tags of elements with a class of `profileLinks`, whereas your `<a>` **are** the elements with the class applied to it. Change it like so:

```
#trends a.profileLinks:link
```

Same goes for the other rule.

Comment: Try again, buddy: http://jsfiddle.net/pv2qx/ - #00f is blue, the default color of links in most browsers...

Comment: Wth it worked for you but didn't work for me ??? Well it should've at least removed the underline cause i had none for text decoration so it didn't matter if the color was blue. Thanks anyways i found a way to do it I placed a span tag around each link repetitive but it atleast worked :D

Comment: Unless you have more `<a>` rules you didn't post here, this should work. Did you check the jsFiddle link above? My edit to your CSS only made the link an orange/red color - the underline goes away, per your ruleset.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by " more <a> rules" ? (I'm new to html and css sorry )  Yea i did check out the link you provided that's why i was freaking out about why it worked for you but not me :P

Comment: Meaning, are there any other rules in your stylesheet that would target hyperlinks? But, you got something to work, so case-closed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other stylesheet overridden to yours?

Try this

```
#trends .profileLinks a:link {
    color:#0000FF !important;
    text-decoration:none;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey try [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/tAZwn/) Just defined color to all links. Change the link color to your desire one.